# DataOutputStream writeObject compilation error

Tags: java, dataoutputstream

I need help writing an object to a file in Java with this code.

```
FileOutputStream objectFOS = new FileOutputStream("Items.dat");
DataOutputStream objectDOS = new DataOutputStream(objectFOS);
objectDOS.writeObject(one);
```

one is of class Item that I defined, and the class implements Serializable.
I keep getting the error message:

```
Error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method writeObject(Item)
location: variable objectDOS of type java.io.DataOutputStream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataOutputStream supports only primitive datatype. To write an object , you may use ObjectOutputStream.

```
FileOutputStream objectFOS = new FileOutputStream("Items.dat");
ObjectOutputStream objectDOS = new ObjectOutputStream(objectFOS);
objectDOS.writeObject(one);
```